# How to modify following jQuery function to work with several different objects?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

On my website I have several hidden div's with comments. Each comment div is for a

different article. Then I have a link which calls a jQuery UI function that expands hidden

div's.

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/g7LwM/18/

The problem, as you can see, is that it expands all hidden div's, where as I only need to

expand one which is related to a article. I can give an id of the article to each hidden

div e.g. `.commentsBox 1 , .commentsBox 2 , .commentsBox 3` But I don't know how to modify

jQuery function so it only expands a .commentsBox with a certain id. So this is my

question, How do I need to modify the code so when I click a `.st_commentsa` link of the article, it expands a hidden .comentsBox of that same article only?

**Full code:**

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".st_commentsa").toggle(function() {
        $(".comentsBox").show("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 200);
    }, function() {
        $(".fb-comments").hide("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 200);
    })

})
</script>

</head>

<body>

<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="st_id">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="st_time">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="st_author">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="st_verification">Click me</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="commentsBox 1" style="display: none;"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"/>
</div>

<br /><br />

<ul>
<li><a href="#" class="st_id">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="st_time">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="st_author">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="st_verification">Click me</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="st_comments">Click me</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="commentsBox 2" style="display: none;"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"/>
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: -1 the question keeps changing - the HTML layout has been changed making it difficult to provide a working answer

Comment: and please have a read of http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php you need to look at when to use a class and when to use an ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".st_comments").toggle(function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').next('div.commentsBox').show("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').next('div.commentsBox').hide("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    })
})
```

I use the closest('ul') has it helps jquery find the thing. the commentsBox div is next to the list element, not the 'a href' one (the one clicked). This method is cleaner, and offers better performance too.

**EDIT** and for your second html:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li > a').toggle(function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').next('div.commentsBox').show("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).closest('ul').next('div.commentsBox').hide("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Not longer relavent since the OP changed the question !

<strike>You can use `$(this)` and `.next()` to only toggle the next element :</strike>

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/g7LwM/16/

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".st_comments").toggle(function() {
        $(this).next().show("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).next().hide("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    })

})
```

UPDATED:

Using unique classes is not a good idea - especially when trying to select them ! you need to use `ID`s and then link the `a` to the div ... for example give the `a` and id of `link1` and the div an id of `link1div`

then you could use the following

http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/g7LwM/20/

HTML:

```
<ul><li><a href="#" id="link1" class="st_comments">Click me</a></li></ul>
<div class="commentsBox" id="link1div" style="display: none;"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"/>
</div>

<br /><br />

<ul><li><a href="#" id="link2" class="st_comments">Click me</a></li></ul>
<div class="commentsBox" id="link2div" style="display: none;"><img src="http://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"/>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".st_comments").toggle(function() {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id') + 'div').show("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $('#'+$(this).attr('id') + 'div').hide("slide", {
            direction: "up"
        }, 300);
    })

})
```

Comment: Hi, I forgot to include that links are in unordered list, I eddied the example, I tested your code it works if there is no unordered list, but if there is it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the point of the UL / LI ? there is a list of 1 item !!! This code will not work for your updated question

Comment: the list doesn't consist of one item, I only specified one that is relevant to the question, there additional 5 items in <ul>, besides the one I provided.

Comment: You need to include all of the HTML you have - as you have already seen not specifying the full code results in answers that will not work.